# .Net Control to do Google Chrome Docking

Tags: .net, google-chrome, components, docking

I like the way that Google Chrome allows you to grab tabs out of a window to create additional windows. Does any one know if there is way to do this style of docking and undocking in my .Net application? Or better yet does any one know if there is a .Net component that can provide this type of functionality?

Comment: One of my favourite features of Chrome without a doubt.

Comment: Never knew this was a feature as I always run Chrome maximized, nice one!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but it looks like [Avalon Dock](http://www.codeplex.com/AvalonDock/)
will give you similar functionality.

Comment: Avalon Docks works well, the only thing you can't seem to do it drag tabs from one window to another like you can in google chrome.

Answer (score 1):

[DevExpress](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Bars/dock_window.xml) has a docking control.  We use it in our app